# How to allow underscore in this 'Password Complexity' regex

Tags: regex

Here it is:

```
/(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/
```

It only passes if the password contains upper case AND lower case letters, and also either 1 digit or 1 special character, however I want underscore _ to count as a special character as well and it currently does not, how can modify this regex so that it will allow underscore to count as a special character?

EDIT: here is the context...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("complexity", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/.test(value);
}, "password is not complex, see requirements above");
```

Comment: To quote the famous quote: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems."

Comment: yeah I totally agree with you, to me it looks like somebody ate a keyboard and then barfed it up

Comment: [“And some people, when confronted with regular expressions, think "I know, I'll use a catchy quote that I remember". Now they have added nothing to the discussion.” – Tomalak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098296/are-regular-expressions-worth-the-hassle#comment-912928)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
/(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*[\W_]+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/
```

aioobe was close replace \W with [\W_]

Just so you know this considers a space a special character.

Also I don't see where you are checking for numbers. EDIT: nevermind I found it. (man complex regexes are like a wheres waldo.)

Here is a simplifed version that does not allow spaces (and it is easyier to maintain)

```
(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_])(?=^.*[^\s].*$).*$
^          ^          ^          ^            ^
|          |          |          |            L--does not contain a whitespace
|          |          |          L--at least one non word character(a-zA-Z0-9_) or _ or 0-9
|          |          L--at least one upper case letter
|          L--at least one lowercase Letter
L--Number of charaters
```

These are your building blocks

```
(?=.*[a-z]) // Whatever is inside the [] meens the string contains at least one charter inside that set.
            // If you wanted a minimum of three lowercase letters you can chain the inner block like so 
               (?=(.*[a-z]){3,})
```

Comment: Speaking of that empty space, how would I make it so empty space was not allowed?

Comment: @Shogun I added some more explanation and a example without white space (but I don't see a legitimate reson for not allowing it)

Comment: `(?=^.*[^\s].*$)` doesn't exclude whitespace, it just ensures that there is at least one non-whitespace character.

Comment: None of your expressions seem to work properly. E.g. in PHP 'aaa1111aA' passes as a valid password although it does not contain any of the special characters. I had to modify the latter one to this for it to correctly catch special characters: `/(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W_])(?=^.*[^\s].*$).*$/`

Comment: Found the following actually disallowing the whitespace: (?=^[\S]*$)

Comment: @zvolkov putting a `^` as the first charactor in a set (`[]`) inverts the result set. Yes doing `[\S]` instead of `[^\s]` will also do it, but both methods produce the [same](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%3F%3D^[^\s]*%24%29) [result](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%3F%3D^[\S]*%24%29). (Also if you really want to be picky the expression would be `(?=^\S*$)`)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain well, I tested both on http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html and (?=^[\S]*$) worked while (?=^.*[^\s].*$) did not. Thanks for the explain regex tool, it's magic!

Answer (score 7):

Any particular reason you want to do all of this in one regex?  Seems to me this would be a lot more readable if you just broke it down:

```
 if (password.length() < 8) return "Password too short!";
 if (!password.matches("\d")) return "Password must contain at least one digit!";
 if (!password.matches("[A-Z]")) return "Password must contain at least one uppercase leter!";
 if (!password.matches("[a-z]")) return "Password must contain at least one lowercase leter!";

 // Password is valid, save it, etc.
```

Comment: see the EDIT made to see why, it's already implemented this way :)

Comment: @Shogun: Why not factor out the checking into a function and then you can just call `validate_complexity(value)` instead of `//.test(value)`? Factoring it out is much more maintainable and readable

Comment: telling me to change what I am doing is not answering my question

Comment: Nod - I wasn't trying to say you should change what you are doing, just take a moment to make sure you aren't looking in the wrong place :)  Note I didn't say "You shouldn't use RE here!".

Answer (score 4):

I suppose your `\W` denotes a special character (It's usually defined as "A non-word character")

So, if you would like to add `_` to that set of characters, you should be able to write `[\W_]`.

(Updated according to Scott Chamberlains comment.)

---

I'm not sure why you have `(?![.\n])`. Do you want to prevent newlines in the password?

Otherwise, this looks like a simplified regexp:

```
String regexp = "(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\\W_\\d]).*$";
for (String s : new String[] {
        "abcdefg",
        "abcdefgh",
        "abCdefgh",
        "abc1efgh",
        "abC1efgh",
        "abC1e@gh",
        "abC1e_gh"}) {

    System.out.println(s + " is " + (s.matches(regexp) ? "ok" : "not ok"));

}
```

Prints

```
abcdefg is not ok
abcdefgh is not ok
abCdefgh is not ok
abc1efgh is not ok
abC1efgh is ok
abC1e@gh is ok
abC1e_gh is ok
```

Comment: Most regex languages count _ as a word charater http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand

Comment: yeah I would figure as much too but it isn't count it when I try

Comment: [^\w_] is incorrect that would be equilivant to [^a-zA-Z0-9__] (notice the two underscores) what you want is [\W_] which is equilvant to [^a-zA-Z0-9_]|_

Answer (score 4):

Do you consider this an acceptable password?

```
Aa8 ½ý_
```

Because your regex matches it.  You might want to change that first lookahead from `(?=^.{8,}$)` to `(?=^[!-~]{8,}$)`, limiting the possibilities to printing ASCII characters (i.e., not whitespace or control characters).  If you want to allow non-ASCII characters it gets a lot more complicated; JavaScript regexes don't do Unicode very well.

Here's how I would write the regex:

```
/^(?=[!-~]{8,}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z]).*$/
```

Like Scott, I don't see the point of this bit: `(?![.\n])`.  All it does is make sure the first character is not a period or a linefeed.  That can't be what you (or the original author) meant, but I can't even guess what the actual intent was.

Answer (score 3):

For future searchers, here's my implementation that includes requiring a special character AND a digit:

```
/(?=^[!-~]{8,}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=^.*[^\s].*$)(?=.*[\d]).*$/
```

Heres an [example](https://gist.github.com/3419644)