# How can I force user to enter password with symbol(s) inside?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, matcher

```
                if (password1.length() >= 15){          
                    final String PasswordPattern = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])[0-9A-Za-z]{15,}$";

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PasswordPattern);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(password1);   

                    if(matcher.matches() == true){                      

                        if (password1.equals(password2)){
                            SavePreferences(password1.toString());
                            //Intent intent = new Intent(LockAppActivity.this, ScreenLockActivity.class);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LockAppActivity.this, PhoneNumActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            pass1.setText("");
                            pass2.setText("");
                            Toast.makeText(LockAppActivity.this,"Both passwords are not equal!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
```

I want user to enter password with at least 15 characters which must consists of Capital and Small letters, numbers and symbols. But I only know how to create pattern with Capital and Small letters and numbers... How can I include all the symbols in the pattern... Kindly check on my pattern code part... thanks

Comment: Be more clearly on "symbols", what do you consider a symbol and what not? Unicode contains a lot of "symbols"...

Comment: All the symbols available on the Android phone keypad

Comment: Not relevant to answering the question, but: A 15 character minimum password, with uppercase, lowercase, numbers and symbols?  Presumably for a cell phone, where entering all this is (at least) a bit tedious?  I would guess that some users will not like that requirement.

Comment: I am developing a security application so a strong and secured password is a must

Comment: Don’t waste your time trying to force usesr to enter funny characters, because they make very little difference to the security of the password. Far more important is password length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the section `(?=.*(\W|_))` to check for anything except alphanumeric (A-Z, a-z, 0-9) symbols. Or, you could specify a set of symbol characters like `(?=.*[\.\*])`. If you do, replace the contents of the `[]` with all the characters you want to allow, using a backslash before each character that has a regex function. (The example shows a section that allows two characters, `.` and `*`.)

Then you'll need top update the section that counts the number of occurrences. Since we're dealing with *all characters* now, we can replace the `[0-9A-Za-z]` with `.`, leaving us with: `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*(\W|_)).{15,}$`. Replace the single `\` with two `\\` since you're placing this in a Java string.

Remember that Android keypads can vary, so not all of them are guaranteed to have the same symbols.

Comment: tip: if you want to put \ mark in regex, you have to type it as \\ in String

Comment: "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^\W_])[0-9A-Za-z]{15,}$"

I get error for this password pattern

Comment: My mistake(s), try "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*(\W|_)).{15,}$".

Answer (score 1):

Its just the example of what you want. I have done this using struts in my project. It satifies your need. You can also add more condition. See this too... http://www.asciitable.com/

```
 if (getNewpassword() != null) {
                    int s;
                    for (int i = 0; i < getNewpassword().length(); i++) {
                        s = (int) getNewpassword().charAt(i);
                        if ((s>=33 && s<=64 )&&(s>=127&&s<=65)) {
                        }
    else
    {
                            errors.add("newpassword1", new ActionMessage("errors.notpwd", "must contains A-Z,a-z and any symbol"));
    }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: the s variable will get the decimal ASCII value of the character by character and checks them. If the values lies between the condition it will submit other the error will show to user

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3721953/339428) answer to another question useful. I'm not sure if it this password constraint is exactly the same as yours, but it seemed similar enough that it might help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3721953/339428