# Regex misunderstanding

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use regex to check for letters only so I used the below method. The problem is that if I have a number before or after the letter, the number is ignored and nothing happens and that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to check for letters ONLY so if I have anything other then letters an error message pops up. If I have letters only it works fine, and If I have numbers only it also works fine, the problem is that if I have a letter and a number it does't work correctly, other than that everything works fine.

```
Regex _regex = new Regex("[A-Z]");
Match Instruction_match = _regex.Match(Instruction_Seperator[1]);

if (!Instruction_match.Success) // "A," or "B," or "C,"...etc.
{
     Messagebox.show("Error, Please letters only");
}
```

note that Instruction_Seperator[1] is taken from the user through a textbox, where the user MUST only input letters nothing before the letters nor after the letters. do u have any idea why the messagebox doesn't popup when I input letters and numbers.

Looking forward for your replies :)

can I have a specific size where if the user exceeds pops up an error, for example if the user is allowed only to input 3 Latin letters and nothing else, is there a length constrain in regex :)

Comment: You probably want to read this http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html. Oh, and you might be able to do this simpler with `Char.IsLetter`

Comment: To make it more clear. They should only enter one Letter from A to Z and nothing else, right? So I would write "^[A-Z]"

Answer (score 5):

That pattern will match any string that contains a capital Latin letter; if it happens to contain any other characters they will be ignored. If you want pattern that will match if the string contains ***only*** capital Latin letters, you'll want to use start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors, as well as a one-or-more quantifier (`+`) after your character class, like this:

```
^[A-Z]+$
```

In the end your code should look like this:

```
Regex _regex = new Regex("^[A-Z]+$");
Match Instruction_match = _regex.Match(Instruction_Seperator[1]);

if (!Instruction_match.Success) // "A," or "B," or "C,"...etc.
{
     Messagebox.show("Error, Please letters only");
}
```

Given the update to your question and some other comments you've made, here are some more patterns you might need to use instead:

- `^[A-Z]{3}$` - This pattern will match exactly three capital Latin characters
- `^[A-Z]{1,3}$` - This pattern will match one, two, or three capital Latin characters
- `^[A-Z]([A-Z]{2})?$` - This pattern will match one or three capital Latin characters

Comment: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) is a very good site that can help people new to regex learn it. I'be been doing complex regexes [for years](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721843/how-to-allow-underscore-in-this-password-complexity-regex/3721953#3721953) but I still reference that site all the time.

Comment: Thank you, works well now I'm still new to this but I'll make sure I read more about regex. again thank you :)

Comment: can I have a specific size where if the user exceeds pops up an error, for example if the user is allowed only to input 3 Latin letters and nothing else, is there a length constrain in regex :)

Comment: @user2486597: `{3}` instead of `+` does that, as explained on the page Scott Chamberlain linked.

Answer (score 1):

Change your pattern to:

```
Regex _regex = new Regex("^[A-Z]+$");
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex you have used `[A-Z]` matches only a single capital letter. Use `[A-Z]+` for any length of continuous capital lettered substring of the input. Use `^[A-Z]+$` which implies that substring is anchored at both start and end position of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you would only like to match one letter, so the only matched string is "D" in the follwoing example, if you want any number of words use ^[A-Z]+$

```
var patterns = new string[] { "12ABC", "D", "A","AB","ABC","A2B3","A1BC", "A123", "123ABC12" };
var regex = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]{1,3}$");
foreach (var pattern in patterns)
{
    var isMatch = regex.Match(pattern);
    if (isMatch.Success)
    Console.WriteLine("Found Matching string {0}", pattern);
}
```

Please look at the modified code, the change for your question is to add {1,3} to the regex pattern, which means up to 3 occurrences of Latin words.

Comment: what if i want to have either 1 or max 3 letters, but only Latin letters nothing else and the user can input to a max. number of three letters