# Allow a new line anywhere in the regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am having a find a replace in a bunch of RTF documents, The basic pattern I need is

```
\{(?:\\\*)?\\field\\fldlock\{\\\*\\fldinst ?MERGEFIELD ?((?:\\.*?)?[\w\[\]]+?)(?:\\.*?)?\}(?:\{\\fldrslt\})?\}
```

However I then found out there could potentialy be a newline before each slash, so it turned in to this.

```
\{(?:\s*\\\*)?\s*\\field\s*\\fldlock\s*\{\s*\\\*\s*\\fldinst\s*MERGEFIELD\s*((?:\\.*?)?[\w\[\]]+?(?:\s*\\.*?)?)?\s*\}(?:\s*\{\s*\\fldrslt\s*\})?\s*\}
```

But then I hit this it fails

```
fees totaling $\protect  {\field\fldlock{\*\fldinst MERGEFIELD ENTEROUTSTANDINGVETERINARYF
EES}}\plain\f0\fs24\prot
```

Is there way have to have it match a new line anywhere in the search too without adding `(?:\r?\n)?` everywhere?

**EDIT**

To clear up confusion on the new lines. I need to keep the newlines in the document, I only want to remove the newlines if they are inside my match, so in the final example I posted it should replace

```
fees totaling $\protect  {\field\fldlock{\*\fldinst MERGEFIELD ENTEROUTSTANDINGVETERINARYF
EES}}\plain\f0\fs24\prot
```

with

```
fees totaling $\protect  ENTEROUTSTANDINGVETERINARYFEES\plain\f0\fs24\prot
```

Comment: _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
regular expressions."  Now they have two problems._ - Jamie Zawinski, on alt.religion.emacs, 8/12/97

Comment: *And some people, when confronted with regular expressions, think "I know, I'll use a catchy quote that I remember". Now they have added nothing to the discussion.* – Tomalak, on [SO, Jul 8 '09 at 14:27](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098296/are-regular-expressions-worth-the-hassle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone can provide a better answer using some tool of regex I do not know about I was able to solve it for this case by changing the searach for the capture group to

```
(\\.*?)?([\w\[\]]+)(\s+\w+)?(\s*\\.*?)
```

I just now have to use four captures instead of one, (this also gives me a set of two capture groups of the actuall printed text, which I need later anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try `Regex.Replace(yourString, "[\r\n]*", "")` before running the rest of your processing logic.

Comment: As I said in the other answer, I need to keep newlines that are not matched inside the regex. I will update the main post.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `\s+` instead.

**EDIT:** If you want to replace all newlines (and other weird whitespace) with one space just run the following before doing other matching:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", " ");
```

Comment: Ok, but how to have have it match that last example where there is a newline in the middle of the word (and have it remove the newline in the process).

Comment: The issue is there are newlines I do want to keep, I just do not want to keep them if they are inside the match. your solution would remove all newlines from the entire document.

Comment: `RegexOptions.Singleline` has no effect on `\s`, only on `.`.