# How to make Regular expression that accepting format "Mr. 5 star hotel & cool bar"

Tags: iphone, regex, nsregularexpression

I need a regular expression that accept the format `"Mr. 5 star hotel & cool bar"` .

How can i create this formate? any idea?
i made  one that i giving here that some what accepting my condition but the problem now i am facing is it not allowing space after '&' and '.' 
the formula is : `^([A-Za-z0-9]+([\\s\\.[&]][A-Za-z0-9]+)*)$`
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *'And some people, when confronted with regular expressions, think "I know, I'll use a catchy quote that I remember". Now they have added nothing to the discussion.'* -- [Tomalak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098296/are-regular-expressions-worth-the-hassle#comment912928_1098296)

Comment: @Shoban what use saying it here? if you know answer then try to help me else just leave it. i am not forcing you but i am just asking you a help.

Comment: Cool down guys. Did I point out anything wrong in OPs question? Just added a quote for fun. @Subin good luck with your question.

Comment: @Shoban, I'm as cool as can be! I also just just added a quote for fun :)

Comment: @Subin Your question is too vague. The string you give isn't really a format. You need to give, say, three examples, or an example that contains tags, e.g. "Mr [number] hotel & [bar description]", and also specify what sort of characters might pop up in your string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do here... but uh,  something like this: http://regex101.com/r/wX9fL0 ?

`/^(\w+)\.\s*(\d+)([^&]+)&(.+)$/`